# Openjdsk throws the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty

Tags: java, spring-boot

URL class giving error while opening a stream

I am using OpenJDK with spring boot and I want to download an image from the URL and store it in the physical file.

I used the channel class to read bytes fastly.

I tried to change the read file using file input stream and JAVA NIO but both are giving same error and I am not setting any trustAnchors because I do not want to use any certificate to. I want to use the default certificate.

```
ReadableByteChannel rbcObj = Channels.newChannel(urlObj.openStream());
FileOutputStream fOutStream = new FileOutputStream("/myfolder/abc.img");
fOutStream.getChannel().transferFrom(rbcObj, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
```

Open JDK throws below error

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1937)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1894)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleException(SSLSocketImpl.java:1877)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1398)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:563)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1512)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1440)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
    at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1038)
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that it is trying to use SSL, so the URL must be `https://...`. I believe that particular error message means either the truststore, required for SSL, is:

1. not set
2. set to a non-existent file
3. set to an existing file that is empty
4. set to an existing file that is NOT empty, but there is a permissions issue